# How to get JSON array out of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, parsing

I'm fairly new to JSON and am trying to extract the array named "steps" and the string "step" in this JSON get request result in angularJS:

[image: Payload]

[image: Payload.data]

However, I cannot get this information by trying the following (which give undefined or error):

```
payload.data.steps
payload.data.steps[0].step
payload.data[0].steps
```

any guidance would be appreciated thanks!

**SOLVED**
Thank you everyone for your thoughtful and thorough answers. I was making a few mistakes including ones with asynchronous http.get results.

For future reference, in my services.js I passed the get request to my controller this way:

```
var recipes = payload.data[0].steps;
```

and in my controller.js I made sure to have it wait for the call to come back (rather than receiving a promise) and then save it to scope:

```
RecipeDetails.getInstructions($scope.details.id).then(function(InstructionPayload){
      $scope.instructions = InstructionPayload;
```

and in my HTML page to display the steps individually:

```
//Steps:
<div ng-repeat="list in instructions track by $index">
<p>{{ list.step }}</p>
```

Comment: `payload.data[0].steps` should work. Maybe you can host the source json on pastebin.com so I can analyze further?

Comment: Can you please share code with `fiddle` or `plnkr` ?

Comment: payload.data[0].steps works when I do it in the services.js file rather than in the controller! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick go at it, hope it helps. I can always update if needed.

```js
function exampleController($scope) {
  $scope.example = [{
    name: "",
    steps: [{
      equipment: [],
      ingredients: [],
      number: 1,
      step: 'Blah'
    }]
  }, {
    name: "",
    steps: [{
      equipment: [],
      ingredients: [],
      number: 2,
      step: 'Bibbidi'
    }]
  }, {
    name: "",
    steps: [{
      equipment: [],
      ingredients: [],
      number: 3,
      step: 'Bobbidi'
    }]
  }, {
    name: "",
    steps: [{
      equipment: [],
      ingredients: [],
      number: 4,
      step: 'Boo'
    }]
  }];

  function extractSteps() {
    $scope.stepArray = [];
    $scope.example.forEach(function(step) {
      if (step.steps && Array.isArray(step.steps)) {
        step.steps.forEach(function(value, index) {
          if (value && value.step) {
            $scope.stepArray.push({
              'step': value.step
            })
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  extractSteps();
}

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('exampleController', exampleController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="exampleController">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="(key, value) in example" ng-bind="value.steps[0].step">
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="value in stepArray">
      <pre>{{value | json}}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have underscore or lodash in you application, you can chain a few things together, like so:

```
_.chain(obj.data) // wrap the data so we can chain transformations
  .map('steps') // gather all the steps arrays from the main array
  .flatten() // smash them into a single array
  .map('step') // grab all the step properties from those
  .value() // return the value -> ["Blah", "Bibbidi", "Bobbidi", "Boo"] from alphapilgrim's example data
```